# strange behaviour of sprintf in avr

Tags: serial-port, avr

I have a code written in codevision AVR for ATmega2560 to send formatted output to USART 0 and 3. My USART 0 is connected is RS232 interface while USART 3 is zigbee interface. When I tested zigbee interface with simple test programs, it was ok so there should not be any problems with zigbee. When using this, USART 0 takes the string without any problems but USART 3 has problems so I decided to post it here to know what is wrong over here.

```
#include <mega2560.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFF_SIZE       200  

unsigned char out_buf[BUFF_SIZE];

void USART0_init(void) /*************** USART 0 ***********************/
{    
    UCSR0A = 0x00;
    UCSR0B |= (1<<RXEN0)|(1<<TXEN0);
    UCSR0C |= (1<<UCSZ01)|(1<<UCSZ00);        
    UBRR0H=0x00;
    UBRR0L=103; //baud rate 9600
}

void USART0_putc(unsigned char data)
{
    while(!(UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)));
    UDR0=data;
}

void USART0_puts(unsigned char* str){
    while(*str) {USART0_putc(*str++);}
}
void USART3_init(void)  /*************** USART 3 ***********************/
{    
    UCSR3A = 0x00;
    UCSR3B |= (1<<RXEN3)|(1<<TXEN3);
    UCSR3C |= (1<<UCSZ31)|(1<<UCSZ30);        
    UBRR3H=0x00;
    UBRR3L=8;   //baud rate 115200;
}

void USART3_putc(unsigned char data)
{
    while(!(UCSR3A & (1<<UDRE3)));
    UDR3=data;
}

void USART3_puts(unsigned char* str){
    while(*str) {USART3_putc(*str++);}
}
```

This code above is for USART 0 and 3.
The code to display through USART 0 and 3 at every 60 seconds is here.

```
if (tick_60sec == 60){    
    tick_60sec = 0;
    axis_store();axis_disp();                
    sens_avg_call();

    t3_l = 1; t6_l = 1;
    t9_l = 1; t12_l = 1;
    t15_l = 1; t17_l = 1;
    t19_l = 1;
}

void sens_avg_call(void)
{
    sprintf(out_buf,"wind current avg: %d",(windc_av/3));    
    USART3_puts(out_buf);
    USART0_puts(out_buf);
    sprintf(out_buf,"wind voltage avg: %d",(windv_av/3));
    USART3_puts(out_buf);
    USART0_puts(out_buf); 
    sprintf(out_buf,"solar current avg: %d",(solc_av/3));
    USART3_puts(out_buf);
    USART0_puts(out_buf);
    sprintf(out_buf,"solar voltage avg: %d",(solv_av/3));
    USART3_puts(out_buf);
    USART0_puts(out_buf);
    sprintf(out_buf,"led current avg: %d",(ledc_av/3));
    USART3_puts(out_buf);
    USART0_puts(out_buf);
    sprintf(out_buf,"battery voltage avg: %d",(battv_av/3));
    USART3_puts(out_buf);
    USART0_puts(out_buf);
    sprintf(out_buf,"temperature avg: %d",(temp_av/3));
    USART3_puts(out_buf);
    USART0_puts(out_buf);
}
```

Comment: You don't gain any speed with using binary literals over oring `_BV()` calls.

Comment: I have edited the register settings above.

Answer (score 0):

From your baud rate divisor settings I can see you're using a 16 MHz clock. For the 115200 baud rate and the divisor setting of 8 you'll have an error of 3.7% which is fairly marginal and I've found some ZibBee modules to be particular about baud rates.

One solution would be to use a more "baud rate friendly" clock speed such as 14.7456 Mhz, you may find [WormFood's AVR Baud Rate Calculator](http://www.wormfood.net/avrbaudcalc.php) useful to select a crystal. You'll need to check the documentation for your module but another solution would be to drop the baud rate to something that will have a lower error at 16 MHz such as 9600 or 38400.